# Were the laser swords in Aryamaan basically lightsabers?

Tags: aryamaan-brahmaand-ka-yodha

There is an Indian TV series known as [*Aaryamaan - Brahmaand Ka Yoddha*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryamaan_%E2%80%93_Brahmaand_Ka_Yodha). It aired for a few episodes in India and then stopped. I was a child when I watched that serial. I didn't know about *Star Wars* then.

The swords used in *Aryamaan* seemed to be some sort of lightsaber. **Is there any official source stating the underlying in-universe technology of the swords used in the TV series?**

Comment: Are you asking if they were a lightsaber rip off or if they were "actual" lightsabers from _Star Wars_?

Comment: Some form of ripoff of light saber

Comment: I don't mean to be unhelpful but if you remember them as lightsabers then surely they were essentially rip off lightsabers?

Comment: Wikipedia quotes the creator as calling the show an "Indian version of the famous Star Wars", but it's not in the citation given. [This article](https://www.microoci.com/aryamaan-brahmaand-ka-yodha-serie-india-star-wars-serie/), written in Catalan, has the article author calling it "a television series inspired by the Star Wars universe", but that's not a quote from anybody. I haven't found any other reference to Star Wars being a direct inspiration for the show.

Comment: Is there any official source stating the technology of the swords used in the TV series @thunderforge

Comment: @codeczar I haven't found anything about it yet; I've never seen the show before today, although having watched a bit of the first episode, I'll agree with the assessment than it's clearly intended to look like Star Wars.

Comment: Can someone suggest what is the similarities between light saber and swords used in the TV series it will answer my question @thelethalcarrot . I don't remember the name used for the sword in the serial

Comment: "the underlying technology of the swords used in the TV series" Is this in-universe (e.g. beams of plasma or whatever) or out-of-universe (e.g. rotoscoping techniques to create the effect)?

Comment: In universe technology @thunderforge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Towards something approaching an answer:

I can't find a definitive source to specifically answer your query, but upon digging, I think I can get close.  You'll have to connect the dots to see the picture:

- Mukesh Khanna [is an engineer](https://www.financialexpress.com/archive/8216i-have-a-strong-grudge-against-the-film-industry8217/52652/) or at least studied engineering before going into acting & producing and is also a blue belt in (an unspecified) martial art.
- Chandrahaas is the weapon Aryamaan seeks in order to win back his kingdom.  It means "smiling like the Moon" and also is the Bow of Lord Shiva.  I take that to mean it sort of glows with some kind of power, and is an obvious link to the lightsaber's glow.
- The weapon is used in identical fashion to the lightsaber -- like a sword
- The weapon depicted in the serial is quite obviously a "lightsaber" that glows in somewhat Moonlike fashion:

[image]

Conclusions:

Any official source is likely to be in Hindi and thus inaccessible to me; interviews with Mr. Khanna seem to be more about Mr. Khanna and his hatred for Bollywood than anything else; and finally, given the obvious sources of inspiration used by Mr. Khanna, I'd offer a fairly strong, three star, reasonably unweaselly assertion that

## Aryamaan's laser sword is indeed basically a lightsaber.

Comment: It looks like in some scenes, like his initial fight in Episode 1, the "lightsaber" has a very clear guard, which is absent in the picture you show above. So they started out more different before becoming basically the same.